# Query Isn't Ordering Right

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 different tables that I'm fetching data from. The first table is Users and the second is mob, which is like friends. Well, I'm limiting 9 rows from the mob row and getting their info from the Users table. They should be in order by income * 10, but they're in some random order. Here's the coding:

```
<?php
$get_mob = mysql_query("SELECT sent_id FROM mob WHERE sender_id=".$id." LIMIT 9");
while($mob_info = mysql_fetch_array($get_mob)) {
$mob_id = $mob_info['sent_id']; 
// Get mob stats
$get_users = mysql_query("SELECT id,username,image,income,last_login FROM users WHERE id=".$mob_id." ORDER BY income");
while($user_info = mysql_fetch_array($get_users)) {
$user_id = $user_info['id'];    
$user_name = $user_info['username'];    
$user_image = $user_info['image'];  
$user_income = $user_info['income'];    
$user_bounty = $user_income * 10;
$user_bonus = $user_bounty / 2;
$user_login = $user_info['last_login']; 
}
echo 
'<div id="MyMobBlock">
<div id="MyMobName"><span title="'.$user_name.'">'.substr($user_name,0,10).'..</span></div>
<div align="center"><img src="'.$user_image.'" width="60" height="60" /></div>
<div class="Success" align="center" title="$'.number_format($top_collect).'">$'.number_format($user_bonus).'</div>
</div>';    
}
?>
```

Here's a picture of it and as you can see they're not in order at all, and theirs way higher incomes than that in my friends list.

[image: Out of order and not showing the correct users]

So what's a way to correct this and show the right people and in order by income?

Comment: in `$get_mob = mysql_query("SELECT sent_id FROM mob WHERE sender_id=".$id." LIMIT 9");` where your `id` come from? Why you using `LIMIT 9`, is that not supposed to be `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Looks like you need to order `$get_mob` other than `$get_users`, for the query for `$get_users` it's pointless to order it as you will only have a single result (considering `id` should be unique).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek can't order the $get_mob by income because the income is from the users table

Comment: @ColourDalnet No it limits to 9 because their's a total of 9 needed displayed, limiting 1 would only display 1 And my id comes from a part of the script I didn't paste requiring connect.php

Comment: @user3059258 It appears that `sender_id` in `mob` relates to `id` in `users`. If that's true why not join and order by `income`?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek How would I do that, I know theirs a join function, but I've never used it before.

Comment: It would look something like so: `SELECT id,username,image,income,last_login FROM users INNER JOIN mob ON id=sender_id ORDER BY income`. And you will only need the single query other than two. Note I don't know how your database and tables look, but will give you an idea on joining.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Looks Pretty accurate! About to test it out!

Comment: You even didn't try my answer, lol.

Comment: @ColourDalnet I know that feeling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
$get_users = "select b.id as id, b.username as username, b.image as image, b.income as income, b.last_login as last_login from mob a inner join users b on a.sent_id = b.id WHERE a.sender_id=".$id." ORDER BY b.income LIMIT 9";

while($user_info = mysql_fetch_array($get_users)) {
$user_id = $user_info['id'];    
$user_name = $user_info['username'];    
$user_image = $user_info['image'];  
$user_income = $user_info['income'];    
$user_bounty = $user_income * 10;
$user_bonus = $user_bounty / 2;
$user_login = $user_info['last_login']; 

echo 
'<div id="MyMobBlock">
<div id="MyMobName"><span title="'.$user_name.'">'.substr($user_name,0,10).'..</span></div>
<div align="center"><img src="'.$user_image.'" width="60" height="60" /></div>
<div class="Success" align="center" title="$'.number_format($top_collect).'">$'.number_format($user_bonus).'</div>
</div>';    
}
```

Comment: Worked Pefectly, and Now I understand how to use the join mysql function! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Your echo isn't in the loop of the ordered query:

```
while($user_info = mysql_fetch_array($get_users)) {
$user_id = $user_info['id'];    
$user_name = $user_info['username'];    
$user_image = $user_info['image'];  
$user_income = $user_info['income'];    
$user_bounty = $user_income * 10;
$user_bonus = $user_bounty / 2;
$user_login = $user_info['last_login']; 
}
echo 
'<div id="MyMobBlock">
<div id="MyMobName"><span title="'.$user_name.'">'.substr($user_name,0,10).'..</span></div>
<div align="center"><img src="'.$user_image.'" width="60" height="60" /></div>
<div class="Success" align="center" title="$'.number_format($top_collect).'">$'.number_format($user_bonus).'</div>
</div>';
```

You're echoing only the **last** row of the `SELECT id,username,image,income,last_login FROM users WHERE id=".$mob_id." ORDER BY income` statement for each result of the `SELECT sent_id FROM mob WHERE sender_id=".$id." LIMIT 9` statement (which is not ordered).

Also, please consider using `mysqli_` and not `mysql_`. Additionally, you might want to use prepared statements (especially for the statements you are executing over and over).

**UPDATE:** Since you seriously have a problem understanding your own code, this is what it's equivalent to:

```
<?php
//You're selecting 9 mobs, NOT ORDERING BY ANYTHING...
$get_mob = mysql_query("SELECT sent_id FROM mob WHERE sender_id=".$id." LIMIT 9");
while($mob_info = mysql_fetch_array($get_mob)) {
    $mob_id = $mob_info['sent_id']; 
    //For each of the 9 mobs, you're only getting the last result of this query:
    $user_info = mysql_query("SELECT id,username,image,income,last_login FROM users WHERE id=".$mob_id." ORDER BY income")->get_last_result(); //Gets the last result form this query
    //Which is the user with the least income for that particular mob

    $user_id = $user_info['id'];    
    $user_name = $user_info['username'];    
    $user_image = $user_info['image'];  
    $user_income = $user_info['income'];    
    $user_bounty = $user_income * 10;
    $user_bonus = $user_bounty / 2;
    $user_login = $user_info['last_login'];

    //You're outputting this last result (the user of this mob with the least income, for THAT SPECIFIC mob)
    echo 
    '<div id="MyMobBlock">
    <div id="MyMobName"><span title="'.$user_name.'">'.substr($user_name,0,10).'..</span></div>
    <div align="center"><img src="'.$user_image.'" width="60" height="60" /></div>
    <div class="Success" align="center" title="$'.number_format($top_collect).'">$'.number_format($user_bonus).'</div>
    </div>';
}
//And you didn't accomplish what you wanted.
?>
```

Comment: I've already done ORDER BY income DESC before I posted this, it did nothing, and my website is over 100 PHP files, so Don't plan on changing 100 files to mysqli anytime soon

Comment: as you can see they're not in any order at all, So what's the issue?

Comment: @user3059258 Wait, the `echo` is not even in the loop. Care to explain?

Comment: I forgot to paste the } It's in the loop

Comment: @user3059258 Read my answer.

Comment: It's in the loop, I just forgot to paste the } at the end of it. Because it's selecting 9 like it's supposed to, it's just ordering them by random, but it should order them by income, Because if you look at the image, it's showing them in random order and it's not even getting the highest incomes.

Comment: @user3059258 It's selecting 9 randomly because the first command isn't ordered. Look at your code -_-".